# Pattern.matcher(s).replaceAll("$1$2$3") Transform only $2 to lowercase

Tags: java, regex

I have a String like this

> final String *text* = "Some Text #AAAA some Other text .." (# with 4 uppercase letters)

```
Pattern patt = Patter.compile("(.*?)(#)([A-Z]{4})(.*?)");
patt.matcher(text ).replaceAll("$1$3$4")
```

remove only the `#` in *text* 
I would have *AAAA* in lowercase, result expected :

> Some Text *aaaa* some Other text ..

How have this result in lower case, only for the four *AAAA*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than use `replaceAll` directly you'll have to do the `appendReplacement` loop yourself.  I would use a simpler regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#([A-Z]{4})");
Matcher mat = pattern.matcher(text);
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
while(mat.find()) {
  mat.appendReplacement(buf, mat.group(1).toLowerCase());
}
mat.appendTail(buf);
```

Normally you have to watch out with `appendReplacement` (and `replaceAll`) and use `Matcher.quoteReplacement` if the replacement string might contain `$` signs or backslashes, but in this case we know that can't happen as group 1 will always be exactly four letters.

Comment: @cl-r I would have preferred to use a StringBuilder but for reasons best known to the designers of Java, `appendReplacement` only works with StringBuffer. I keep hoping they'll introduce an overload taking `Appendable` but it hasn't happened yet...

Comment: In fact there's a [bug report](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5066679) dating back to 2004 for this, yet Java 8 still has only the StringBuffer version :-(

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(text);
matcher.matches();
String res = matcher.group(1) + matcher.group(3).toLowerCase() + matcher.group(4);
```

Answer (score 1):

here is an oneliner:

```
String text2 = text.replaceFirst("(?<=#)[A-Z]{4}", text.replaceAll(".*?#([A-Z]{4}).*", "$1").toLowerCase());
```

take your example:

```
final String text = "Some Text #AAAA some Other text ..";
        String text2 = text.replaceFirst("(?<=#)[A-Z]{4}", text.replaceAll(".*?#([A-Z]{4}).*", "$1").toLowerCase());
        System.out.println(text2);
```

will output:

```
Some Text #aaaa some Other text ..
```

Comment: This solution is not extensible to multiple instances of `#` followed by 4 capital letters

Comment: @nhahtdh ture. but it is not OP wanted. he has `"(.*?)(#)..."` in his code

Comment: It is lazy, so it will work even if there are more instances.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    String matched = "";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(#)([A-Z]{4})(.*?)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Some Text #AAAA some Other text");
    if (matcher.find()) {   
        matched =  matcher.group(1) + matcher.group(3).toLowerCase() + matcher.group(4);
    }
    System.out.println(matched);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the [`Matcher.replaceAll()` API page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29):

> Note that backslashes (`\`) and dollar signs (`$`) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string. Dollar signs may be treated as references to captured subsequences.

This sounds exactly like the problem you're facing...